# How to prove $(1 + x)^{n} \leq 1 + 2nx$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inequality, polynomials, taylor-expansion

I am currently working on a math problem, and it boils down to proving $(1 + x)^{n} \leq 1 + 2nx$, for a small $x$

By the Binomial expansion, it is clear that $$(1 + x)^n= 1+ nx + \frac{n(n-1)}{ 2!}x^2 + \frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{3!}x^3 + \cdots$$

However, how can we prove that $$nx \geq \frac{n(n-1)}{ 2!}x^2 + \frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{3!}x^3 + \cdots $$
which would prove my claim.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try induction?

Comment: The claim is false if $nx<0$. Do you require the result for real $n$ or only for integral $n$?

Comment: This follows by the fact that $(1+x)^n$ equals $1+2nx$ at $x=0$, but the derivative of $(1+x)^n$ at $x = 0$ is less than the derivative of $1+2nx$ at $x = 0$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since $(1 + x)^n$ is convex for $x \ge -1$, it lies below all of its secant lines. This gives that for any $x_0 > 0$ we have

$$(1 + x)^n \le 1 + \frac{(1 + x_0)^n - 1}{x_0} x, x \in [0, x_0].$$

So it suffices to choose $x_0 > 0$ small enough such that $(1 + x_0)^n - 1 \le 2n x_0$. We can take $x_0 = \frac{1}{n}$, since $\left( 1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)^n - 1 < e - 1 < 2 = \frac{2n}{n}$, so we get the slightly stronger result

$$(1 + x)^n \le 1 + (e-1)nx, x \in \left[ 0, \frac{1}{n} \right].$$

Answer (score 2):

$(1 + x)^n = 1 + nx + O(x^2) = 1 + 2nx(1/2 + O(x)) \leq 1 + nx$ when the $O(x)$ term is $\leq 1/2$. The reason for the first equality is that a polynomial $p(x)$ of order $n$ is $O(x^n)$ as $x \to 0$. This is easy to prove, because $p(x)/x^n \to a_n$ as $x \to 0$, so in fact $p(x) \sim a_nx^n$.

Comment: This reasoning does not take into account that the claimed inequality is wrong for negative $x$.

Answer (score 2):

One can continue from the binomial expansion, for $x>0$ this gives estimates against a geometric series
\begin{align}
(1+x)^n&= 1+nx\left(1+\frac{(n-1)x}{2}+\frac{(n-1)(n-2)x^2}{2·3}+...\right)
\\
&\le 1+nx\left(1+\frac{(n-1)x}{2}+\frac{(n-1)^2x^2}{2^2}+...\right)
\\
&\le 1+\frac{nx}{1-\frac{(n-1)x}{2}}
\end{align}
For the convergence of the series one needs $\frac{(n-1)x}{2}<1$, then for the claim $\frac{(n-1)x}{2}\le\frac12$, thus for $n\ge 2$ and $0\le x\le\frac1{n-1}$ the claimed inequality is true, for $n=0,1$ it is true for all $x>0$.

For $x<0$ the claim is wrong, as by the Bernoulli inequality
$$
(1-|x|)^n\ge 1-n|x|>1-2n|x|=1+2nx.
$$

Comment: Apologies for my mistyping: I meant $n=\frac12$, not $x=\frac12$. The coefficient of $x^2$ in the parenthesized series is $$\frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{2·3}$$ in the first line, and in the second line it is $$\frac{(n-1)^2}{2^2}.$$ Substituting $n=\frac12$ gives $\frac18x^2$ as the first-line term and $\frac1{16}x^2$ as the corresponding term in the second line. I hope that, with this correction, my comment makes sense now!

Comment: In addition to $x>0$, the restriction $n>1$ needs to be stated at the outset (albeit being implied by the condition $x<1/(n−1)$ derived later). Otherwise, for example, the first inequality is invalid in the case $n=\frac12$ [typo corrected], when the coefficient of $x^2$ in the parenthesized series is $\frac18$ in the first line but only $\frac1{16}$ in the second.

Comment: It is not outright stated, but the use of $n$ instead of, e.g., $\alpha$ for the exponent, and using the binomial formula instead of the binomial series strongly hints that $n$ is assumed to be integer.

Comment: Agreed. However, given the lax standard of adherence to notational convention on this site, I think that we need an explicit statement defining the domain of $n$ here. Although the statement to be proved holds as well for (suitably bounded) real $n$ as for integral $n$, the integral case can be tackled with a more elementary proof—in particular, from first principles by induction.

Answer (score 0):

For $|x|<\frac \epsilon n$, $$\left|\frac{(n)_k}{k!}x^k\right|<\frac{\epsilon^{k-1}}{k!}|nx|,$$

where $(n)_k=n(n-1)\cdots(n-k+1)$. And thus the absolute value of RHS is smaller than $$\frac{|nx|}{\epsilon}\sum_{k\ge 2}\frac{\epsilon^k}{k!}=\frac{|nx|}{\epsilon}(e^{\epsilon}-1-\epsilon)\le \epsilon|nx|.$$

when $\epsilon$ is small enough.

Comment: Which is smaller than $nx$ if $x>0$. The claim is wrong for $x<0$.